# revalidatePath fails when used with generateStaticParams

Tags: javascript, next.js

I wanted to use ISR to render my blog page, so I used generateStaticParams and set dynamicParams to true. The static page was successfully generated during the build, and the page could be updated through revalidatePath after the blog was updated. This is really great. .

But after I add a new blog in the CMS system, I cannot update the interface through revalidatePath. Is there any good solution?

Additional information

next: 13.5.1
react: 18.2.0

I hope that newly added blogs in CMS can also be updated through revalidatePath

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.